# efitools issue on UBUNTU 20.04.6 LTS

Tags: command-line, apt, 12.04, software-installation, updates

```
I cannot run efi-readvar command to check the secure boot variables on my system, I have installed
efitools utility but when I run efi-readvar command I get the below output, it seems the package never was installed at all.

Do you know what the problem is? or what should the path location to run it?


luis@luis-04:~$ sudo apt install efitools
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  gir1.2-goa-1.0 libxmlb1
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  mtools
Suggested packages:
  floppyd
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  efitools mtools
0 upgraded, 2 newly installed, 0 to remove and 22 not upgraded.
Need to get 324 kB of archives.
After this operation, 1 420 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Get:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 mtools amd64 4.0.24-1 [191 kB]
Get:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/universe amd64 efitools amd64 1.8.1-0ubuntu2 [133 kB]
Fetched 324 kB in 1s (637 kB/s)
Selecting previously unselected package mtools.
(Reading database ... 166109 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../mtools_4.0.24-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking mtools (4.0.24-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package efitools.
Preparing to unpack .../efitools_1.8.1-0ubuntu2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking efitools (1.8.1-0ubuntu2) ...
Setting up mtools (4.0.24-1) ...
Setting up efitools (1.8.1-0ubuntu2) ...
Processing triggers for install-info (6.7.0.dfsg.2-5) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.9.1-1) ...

luis@luis-04:~$ sudo efi-readvars
sudo: efi-readvars: command not found
```

Comment: fixed it, typo command.   efi-readvar
Variable PK has no entries
Variable KEK has no entries
Variable db has no entries
Variable dbx has no entries
Variable MokList has no entries